# Starting bash like pseudo terminal with nodejs

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, tty

I am developing a node cli app which starts a bash like pseudo terminal. User should be able to execute normal bash commands in that terminal like `cp`, `cd`, `mkdir` etc. For eg.,

```
dummy-linux-user:~$ my-node-cli-cmd
Bingo!
node-based-bash:~$
```

Tried using this package https://github.com/substack/bashful but it doesn't give autocomplete like a normal bash terminal does and it exits the node process for a `command not found` error. I want to show a `tty` like terminal to the User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After skimming through a lot of articles and blogs I found a solution for my question in following npm packages,

1. https://github.com/dthree/vorpal
2. https://github.com/dthree/cash

Hope this findings help someone else in our wonderful community. :)